# Objective C blocks and variables

Tags: variables, objective-c-blocks

```
+ (NSArray *)getArrayOfBubblesWithTitles:(NSArray *)titles andMainBubble:(BubbleContainer *)mainB {
    UIColor *c = mainB.colour;
    Corner corner = [Styles getCornerForPoint:mainB.frame.origin];

    NSMutableArray *blocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUInteger count = titles.count;
    CGSize size = mainB.frame.size;
    //TODO: calculation blocks frame
    for (int a = 0; a < titles.count; a++) {
        PositionCalculationBlock x = ^{
            return [SimpleSelectionView getPositionOfObjectAtIndex:a outOfBubbles:count size:size fromCorner:corner];
        };

        [blocks addObject:x];
    }

    NSMutableArray *m = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int a = 0; a < titles.count; a++) {
        [m addObject:[[BubbleContainer alloc] initSubtitleBubbleWithFrameCalculator:blocks[a] colour:c title:titles[a] andDelegate:NO]];
    }

    return m;
}
```

I am not sure about whether my blocks will work right regarding the use of variables. In apple docs it says `Any changes are reflected in the enclosing lexical scope, including any other blocks defined within the same enclosing lexical scope.` I'm not sure what this means but i think it means that where i use the variable `a` in the for statement, only the highest value of a will be used in every block instead of 0-count. Also does using those instance variables (count, size) avoid having a strong pointer to objects like `mainB`? This is hard to test. I am far away from being able to run my code, so if you have any knowledge about blocks could you criticise?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is enabled by default

Answer (score 2):

First, realize that the line you quote:

> [*Any changes are reflected in the enclosing lexical scope, including any other blocks defined within the same enclosing lexical scope.*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Block.html)

applies specifically and only to block-mutable variables, i.e. variables that carry the `__block` modifier. You don't have any block-mutable variables in the code snippet you've shown us, so that line doesn't apply.

> i think it means that where i use the variable a in the for statement, only the highest value of a will be used in every block instead of 0-count

Variables used in a block but defined in an enclosing scope are normally read-only -- the compiler will complain that the variable isn't assignable if try to make a change. To make changes, the variable needs to be marked as block-modifiable using the `__block` modifier. Changes made to a block-modifiable variable are reflected in the enclosing scope.

Here's an example:

```
{
    __block int anInteger = 42;

    void (^testBlock)(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"inside the block anInteger is: %i", anInteger);
        anInteger = 96;
    };

    NSLog(@"before the assignment anInteger is: %i", anInteger);
    anInteger = 84;

    NSLog(@"before the block anInteger is: %i", anInteger);
    testBlock();
    NSLog(@"after the block anInteger is: %i", anInteger);
}
```

The output is:

```
before the assignment anInteger is: 42
before the block anInteger is: 84
inside the block anInteger is: 84
after the block anInteger is: 96
```

Comment: For the second bit, what I mean is that I'm worried that `a` is a pointer to that variable so when the `blocks[a]` bit is called its always essentially `blocks[count]` instead of `blocks[3]` or whatever. Also the variables count and size, do I have to do that to stop it creating an extra strong pointer to those objects and therefore have retain problems?

Comment: @user1726450: `a` is a variable. Also, `count` and `size` are not object pointers.